# MySQL merge two tables and get sum

Tags: mysql, join, union

i have a `tableA`:

```
+------+--------+-------+
| name | code   | num   |
+------+--------+-------+
| A    | no1    | 300   |
| A    | no2    | 100   |
+------+--------+-------+
```

i also have a `tableB`:

```
+------+--------+-------+
| name | code   | num   |
+------+--------+-------+
| A    | no1    | -100  |
| A    | no5    | 77    |
| B    | no7    | 2     |
+------+--------+-------+
```

My goal is want to get `tableC` like this:

```
+------+--------+-------+
| name | code   | num   |
+------+--------+-------+
| A    | no1    | 200   |
| A    | no2    | 100   |
| A    | no5    | 77    |
| B    | no7    | 2     |
+------+--------+-------+
```

i used union and join,but the result is not right,please tell me how to get `TableC`?

Comment: Show use your code, otherwise it's pretty hard to give you a good answer.

Comment: @Forbs,my code :select TableB.name,TableB.code ,TableB.num+IFNULL(tableA.num,0) as s
from tableA  Join tableB on tableA.name = tableB.name;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, instead of `JOIN` what you need is `UNION`. You can use "`UNION ALL`" or "`UNION`", it depends if you want the duplicated rows or not.

In any case, after the `UNION`, group that result into a subquery to get the `SUM()`

```
SELECT
u.name,
u.code,
SUM(u.num),
FROM
(
SELECT name, code, num FROM tableA
UNION ALL
SELECT name, code, num FROM tableB
) u
GROUP BY u.name, u.code
```